# Sending an email message in WP7 on unhandled exception

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a way to send a email message with the details when an unhandled exception occurs in a WP7 app?

I've seen the WCF logging/email sending approach, but I don't have a place to publicly host a service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at Andy Pennell's "[little watson](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2010/11/01/error-reporting-on-windows-phone-7.aspx)." It works pretty well.

Comment: this is the one i'm using in my apps, and it works pretty well.

Comment: has anyone been able to use the "WCF message sending" approach to a hosted web service but doing it in the Application_UnhandledException handler instead of when the app relaunches?  It appears that WP7 won't let new threads get created when you get to this state, so even though you can send a message using HttpWebRequest, BeginGetResponse will never return and the message will never be sent...

Comment: What if the content exceeds 64K? emailcomposetask gives exception "The size of input should not exceed 64K". How to handle it?

Comment: @JohnGardner I launch EmailComposeTask in UnhandleException, but WP7 doesnot execute it, is this the reason Andy Pennell must store error message in file, then read it ?

Comment: dunno, you'd have to ask Andy :)

Answer (score 1):

The only other option you have is to use the [EmailComposeTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.emailcomposetask%28VS.92%29.aspx). This leaves you at the mercy of the user to send the message, because it will give you their email address, but its the only way currently to send a mail message without a WCF service.

Example 1:

```
private void emailAddressChooserTask_Completed(object sender, EmailResult e) 
{ 
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK) 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("Selected email :" + e.Email); 

        //in-real world application user expect to select it from his contacts and if not found enter manually. 
        //EmailComposeTask emailComposeTask = new EmailComposeTask(); 
        //emailComposeTask.To = e.Email; 
        //emailComposeTask.To = saveEmailAddressTask.Email; 
        //emailComposeTask.Body = "WP7 Emails Demo"; 
        //emailComposeTask.Cc = "testmail2@test.com"; 
        //emailComposeTask.Subject = "Windows Phone 7"; 
        //emailComposeTask.Show(); 
    } 
}
```

Example 2:

```
private void composeMail_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    EmailComposeTask emailComposeTask = new EmailComposeTask(); 
    emailComposeTask.To = "chris@example.com"; 
    emailComposeTask.To = saveEmailAddressTask.Email; 
    emailComposeTask.Body = "WP7 Emails Demo"; 
    emailComposeTask.Cc = "testmail2@test.com"; 
    emailComposeTask.Subject = "Windows Phone 7"; 
    emailComposeTask.Show(); 
}
```

Souce: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/1-how-to-perform-email-tasks-in-a-wp7-app

Answer (score 1):

I use the following in my app, it is a little convoluted but works. The following code is in App.xaml.cs:

```
/// <summary>
/// Indicates whether the application needs to quit due to a previous exception
/// </summary>
private static bool _appMustQuit = false;

/// <summary>
/// Exception class that will be unhandled causing application to quit
/// </summary>
private class AppQuitException : Exception {}



// Code to execute on Unhandled Exceptions
private void Application_UnhandledException( object sender,
                                             ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e )
{
  if( ( e.ExceptionObject is AppQuitException ) == false ) {
    Debug.WriteLine( "App:Application_UnhandledException - " + e.ToString() );

    if( Debugger.IsAttached ) {
      // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
      Debugger.Break();

    } 

    // Compose error report
    StringBuilder report = new StringBuilder( 1024 );

    report.AppendFormat( "{0}", LangResources.ErrorReportContent );
    report.AppendFormat( "Message: {0}\n", e.ExceptionObject.Message );
    if( e.ExceptionObject.InnerException != null ) {
      report.AppendFormat( "Inner: {0}\n", e.ExceptionObject.InnerException.Message );
    }
    report.AppendFormat( "\nStackTrace: {0}\n", e.ExceptionObject.StackTrace );

    if( MessageBox.Show( "Unexpected Error", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel ) 
        == MessageBoxResult.OK ) {
      e.Handled = true;

      // Email the error report
      Tasks.ComposeEmail( "\"Developer\" <your@emailaddress.com>", "MyApp Error Report",
        report.ToString() );
      _appMustQuit = true;
    }
  }
}


// Code to execute when the application is activated (brought to foreground)
// This code will not execute when the application is first launched
private void Application_Activated( object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e )
{
  var state = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State;

  if( state.ContainsKey( "AppMustQuit" ) ) {
    throw new AppQuitException();

  } else {
    // Restore other tombstoned variables

  }
}

// Code to execute when the application is deactivated (sent to background)
// This code will not execute when the application is closing
private void Application_Deactivated( object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e )
{
  if( _appMustQuit ) {
    state["AppMustQuit"] = true;

  } else {
    // Save other variables for tombstoning

  }
}
```

`Tasks` is a static class with a bunch of helper functions from the `Microsoft.Phone.Tasks` namespace.

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;

namespace MyApp
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Utility class for performing various phone tasks
  /// </summary>
  public static class Tasks
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Composes an email using the specified arguments
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="to">The recepient(s) of the email</param>
    /// <param name="subject">Email subject</param>
    /// <param name="body">Email contents</param>
    /// <param name="cc">The recipient(s) on the cc line of the email</param>
    public static void ComposeEmail( string to, string subject, string body,
                                     string cc = "" )
    {
      var task = new EmailComposeTask() {
        To = to,
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body,
        Cc = cc,
      };
      task.Show();
    }
  }
}
```

To explain the code a little, using the [`EmailComposeTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.emailcomposetask%28VS.92%29.aspx) causes your app to be tombstoned. Since I do not want to continue executing the app after an unhandled exception I save a boolean to the `PhoneApplicationService`'s [`State`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.state%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) dictionary so that after the user sends the email, when the app re-awakens I can look for this boolean and throw another exception that is intentionally unhandled. This second exception causes the app to quit.

Comment: quitting the app via an unhandled exception is kindof considered a "no no".  all unhandled exceptions end up generating a crash report on the device (wasting battery), which will then get uploaded to microsoft (if you have reporting turned on), which will just waste time and effort for everyone as the phone team goes through all of the submitted crashes to make sure it isn't a phone issue.  If you want to quit, just let the user use back to quit, don't force-quit your app....

Comment: see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2011/02/23/this-is-not-the-exit-you-are-looking-for.aspx

Comment: @John Gardner: I would argue that aborting the app (via unhandled exception) instead of expecting the user to be a good citizen and navigate backwards until he quits the app depends on what your app does. The code I posted is from a password manager, it is unacceptable to me to allow the user to potentially continue using the app when it is in an in-deterministic state (after an exception was thrown). Doing so may cause corruption of the stored user data. I do spend a significant amount of time testing to fix bugs and minimize exceptions being thrown, so this code will only be executed rarely.

Comment: Also, the app does not terminate unexpectedly, it warns the user that an exception has occurred and gives him the choice of sending an error report. Irrespective of whether they send the report or not, the app then terminates. The app I used this in has passed certification several times.

Comment: there are solutions to make the app "unwind" the back stack all the way to the first page, and then the user just has to press back once to quit.

Comment: Of course, trouble is you have no way of forcing the user to hit the back button once more. They might decide to continue to use the app. You could set a boolean on an unexpected exception and disable all controls that allow navigation / editing on the main page and unwind back to that page, then the app is unusable until the user quits, but that is just annoying IMHO. Peter Torr suggests declaring an exception class which is intentionally unhandled to quit from an unstable state (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/01/exiting-a-windows-phone-application.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If somebody is looking for Email messages in background (without loading EmailComposeTask) then [MailMessage](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MailMessage/) might be the best option so for, it also allows attachments which EmailComposeTask does not supports at all. it would allow you to send emails without bothering the users in background using your own gmail or anyother account.

you can get it from NuGet `Install-Package MailMessage` to give it a try, However I haven't used it myself so may be you need to buy it from [authors site](http://www.geekchamp.com/marketplace/components/livemailmessage) its only in $29.99 its really worth paying for it. Free version also works but it shows a popup message in application before sending an email.